# Object-Oriented FizzBuzz in Ruby

Tags: object-oriented, ruby, fizzbuzz

I don't use Ruby on a regular basis, but I felt inspired to write an extensible, object-oriented version of FizzBuzz to sharpen my skills. I welcome all feedback.

The main class:

```
class FizzBuzzer
  def initialize(*tests)
    @tests = tests
  end

  def run(values)
    result = []
    values.each do |value|
      str = ''
      @tests.each do |test|
        str << test.word if test.satisfied_by? value
      end
      str = value.to_s if str.empty?
      result << "#{str}\n"
    end
    result.join
  end
end
```

Sample test operation classes:

```
class ModuloTester
  attr_accessor :word

  def initialize(modulo, word)
    @modulo = modulo.to_i
    @word = word
  end

  def satisfied_by?(number)
    (number % @modulo).zero?
  end
end

class SquareRootTester
  attr_accessor :word

  def initialize(word)
    @word = word
  end

  def satisfied_by?(number)
    (Math.sqrt(number) % 1).zero?
  end
end
```

In use:

```
fizz_buzzer = FizzBuzzer.new ModuloTester.new(3, 'Fizz'), ModuloTester.new(5, 'Buzz')
puts fizz_buzzer.run 1..100

puts

fizz_buzzer = FizzBuzzer.new SquareRootTester.new('(PerfectSquare)')
puts fizz_buzzer.run 1..10
puts fizz_buzzer.run 20..30
puts fizz_buzzer.run 45..55
```

Which produces the expected output. Is this idiomatic Ruby? Is the naming scheme acceptable? What can be improved?

Comment: I like your idea of passing test classes into the constructor for FizzBuzzer. I recommend having ModuloTester and SquareRootTester inherit from one class, and using [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html) methods like [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) and [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) for the `run` method.

Comment: Also, your naming scheme looks fine.

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy Could you please write answers as answers, and not as comments? For more information see ["your code looks correct answers"](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94/should-your-code-seems-fine-answers-be-acceptable)

Comment: @NicolasMcCurdy I thought about using an inheritance hierarchy, but I keep hearing about the power of duck typing in Ruby, so I just decided to implement the same methods. How common is using inheritance in Ruby code versus just duck typing?

Comment: @cbojar Inheritance and duck-typing aren't mutually exclusive, though. Both are used in Ruby. So is composing classes with modules (such as `Enumerable` in 200_success' answer). Duck-typing is basically what you'd use an interface or protocol for in other OOP languages, and inheritance is regular inheritance (e.g. `Car` inheriting from `Vehicle`). In your code, there isn't much to inherit though, so duck-typing is a good solution. Just think of duck-typing as you implementing an interface, and inheritance as regular inheritance.

Comment: @Flambino I'm so used to statically typed languages that sometimes I feel the need to create inheritance hierarchies in dynamic languages and I need to stop myself and remember that duck typing can be just as powerful and perhaps even more useful. That's why, in this piece of code, I went for duck typing to try to make myself more comfortable with the idea in a language that really embraces it.

Comment: @cbojar Good idea - and again, duck-typing does make sense for your code. But speaking of language features, doing FizzBuzz this way is of course overkill compared to using blocks (which is another of Ruby's strengths). E.g. `1.upto(100).each { |n| s = {"Fizz" => 3, "Buzz" => 5}.map { |k,v| k if (n % d).zero? }; puts s.any? ? s.join : n }` (would look nicer with proper linebreaks)

Comment: @cbojar bah, typo in my previous comment; it should be `(n % v).zero?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd like to suggest two changes to your interface.

- **Implement `Enumerable`.**  Your object accepts an `Enumerable`; it would be nice if it also acted as an `Enumerable`.  All you have to do is `include Enumerable` and rename `run` → `each`, and then it behaves more like the way a Rubyist would like to see.
- **Remove the separate calls to `#satisfied_by?` and `#word`.**  I find it awkward that `FizzBuzzer` should have to know about the workings of the tester objects like that.  Why not just have the tester return a truthy output value to indicate that it has performed a transformation?

In addition, I would prefer to see the invocations of `FizzBuzzer.new` and `fizz_buzzer.run` written with parentheses, for readability.  There appears to be a consensus among [multiple Ruby style guides](https://stackoverflow.com/q/616037/1157100) that parentheses should only be omitted for simpler or specialized calls such as `puts`, `include`, `attr_accessor`, or methods that take no arguments.

```
class FizzBuzz
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(*transforms)
    @transforms = transforms
  end

  def each(values=1..Float::INFINITY)
    values.each do |value|
      words = @transforms.map { |transform| transform.transform(value) }
      yield words.any? ? words.join('') : value.to_s
    end
  end
end

class ModuloTransform
  def initialize(modulo, word)
    @modulo = modulo.to_i
    @word = word
  end

  def transform(number)
    (number % @modulo).zero? ? @word : nil
  end
end

class SquareRootTransform
  def initialize(word)
    @word = word
  end

  def transform(number)
    (Math.sqrt(number) % 1).zero? ? @word : nil
  end
end

fb = FizzBuzz.new(ModuloTransform.new(3, 'Fizz'),
                  ModuloTransform.new(5, 'Buzz'))
# FizzBuzz naturally works from 1 to infinity.  This is one way to limit
# the results to the first 100.
fb.take(100).each { |word| puts word }

fb = FizzBuzz.new(SquareRootTransform.new('(PerfectSquare)'))
# This is another way to do FizzBuzz only for certain values.
fb.each(1..100) { |word| puts word }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I like the use of `Enumerable`, +1 on that! As to the two methods, I felt like it might be a tell-don't-ask situation, but I figured I'd see how people responded. +1 there too! As to the parens, I usually work in those "parens everywhere!" languages (and so also find it more readable), but I've heard that spurious parens are not very Ruby. I guess my concerns were overblown there. Lastly, quick question. In the def of `FizzBuzz#each`, you use `values=nil`, then set the default below. Is there a reason not to do `values = 1..Float::INFINITY`?

Comment: See Rev 2. I've corrected the handling of the default argument for `#each`, and explained the recommendation for parentheses.

Comment: This is an excellent code review. I appreciate the efforts you put in, and will note the tips you have provided. Thank you. Answer accepted!